# a question about memoir log file

Tags: memoir

I use the memoir class and in the first section of the log file there are a lot of lines like the following

```
\binding=\skip48
\spinemargin=\skip49
\foremargin=\skip50
\uppermargin=\skip51
\lowermargin=\skip52
\headdrop=\skip53
\normalrulethickness=\skip54
---------------------------
\lightrulewidth=\dimen115
\cmidrulewidth=\dimen116
\belowrulesep=\dimen117
\belowbottomsep=\dimen118
---------------------------
```

I understand that the left hand side quantities represent configurable parameters, but what are the right hand side quantities \skipXX, \dimenXXX (as well as many others, as \countXX) and where they are defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the internal numbers of the registers that are created when `memoir` issues as `\newdimen` or `\newlength` command. Each register has a number.  In the original TeX there were only 256 of them, but in modern TeX there are 32768.

As David says in his comment, the internal register numbers are not useful to you as a user; you should use the actual lengths that are defined.

Comment: Can i use them in some way, or they are printed just for information to the user? generally speaking, memoir prints a lot of info in the log file, and i wonder if this info is useful or not.

Comment: @AthanasiosMargaris they are only useful for debugging, for example if some package doesn't use the official allocation macros (or there is a bug in those allocation macros) you can end up with two names being defined to be the same register which is very confusing without that log information, if `\uppermargin` and `\lowermargin` were both `\skip50` then `\setlength\uppermargin{...}` would also change `\lowermargin`

Comment: Since this INFO is not useful to the end user, is it possible to prevent its append in the log file? I would like to use a smaller log file with only the important error messages and warning.

Comment: @AthanasiosMargaris No, this is not possible. The log is designed to be a full record of the TeX run.  You editor may have a way of filtering some of the stuff, when it displays the log. I use TeXShop, for example, and it can filter out what log information is displayed.